# PDF Digital Signature error: Expecting a Name for a Dictionary entry, found Origami::Annotation::AppearanceStream instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, digital-signature

I am trying to digitally sign the pdf but the code `streamN.Resources.add_xobject(Name.new("n0"),dsblank)` is giving the above specified error. I am unable to resolve the error.

my dsblank code:

```
dsblank = Annotation::AppearanceStream.new.setFilter(:FlateDecode)
    dsblank.Type=Name.new("XObject")
    dsblank.Resources = Resources.new
    dsblank.BBox = [ 0, 0, width, height ]
    dsblank.draw_stream('% DSBlank')
```

I guess the line  `dsblank.Type=Name.new("XObject")` is not working at all.

I am using Origami gem with rails.